# Width percentage value not being applied to element

Tags: html, css, sass

I am styling an element in HTML using Sass, and when setting the width of an element using percentages, it is not applied.

Could this be due to me setting the parent element's width and height using "content-max"?

Here is a basic version of the code I am using, the idea is for the parent's size to be limited by the image size (which works), and for the text overlay to be half the width and the full height of the container element (hence me using 50 and 100 percent respectively).

```
<div class="container">
      <img src="image.png" alt="A square image">
      <div class="text-overlay">
                
      </div>
</div>
```

The separately complied Sass is as follows:

```
.container {
        
     display: block;
     position: relative;
     width: max-content;
     height: max-content;
        
     img {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 0;
     }
        
     .text-overlay {
        
           display: flex;
           position: absolute;
           width: 50%;
           height: 100%;
           z-index: 1;
     }
}
```

Both HTML and SCSS are written in different files and correctly complied where necesary.

Comment: Do you know you cannot use SASS directly in your HTML? This needs to be compiled first. If you had valid CSS (which this is not) there would be no problem.

Comment: At least, not until [CSS Nesting](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/) becomes [implemented in any browser](https://caniuse.com/css-nesting)...

Comment: Sorry I was not clear about this @DirkJ.Faber, & Heretic-Monkey, it is not clear in my code, as I just set it as an example, I am compiling the sass file separate from the HTML, I will edit it now

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber actually it turns out this solution would not work, as CSS (SASS in this context) needs the parent element to have a pre specified width value for a child element a relative % sizing to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can **not** write Sass directly inside your HTML markup. It has to be compiled first.

In your example you are using nesting, which is not valid CSS3 code, so to fix this behavior you either have to write plain CSS like the snippet below *or* compile your Sass before you apply it to your HTML.

---

About your actual question, the positioning you are trying to archieve is working, when you hardcore the `width` and `height` to the `.container` element.

---

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container .text-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  color: red;
  opacity: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/793/200/200.jpg?hmac=3DeE830wjdSShKq_h_iFtV_jAxf43FO4xx-sivW0Q_Y">
  <div class="text-overlay">
    Overlay
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I had not written my example correctly, the Sass is written in its corresponding file and complied accordingly, as for the answer to my question, I appreciate to see the hardcoded version working as should, but that is what I am trying to avoid, would it not be possible using the current setup?